# get link and PID of process calling default web browser

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04, default-browser

I would like to ask whether someone knows a way how you might get a link with a PID of a process that is calling a "website open" request to operating system.

Example:

You click a button in a application that opens default browser with a link that is that application requesting.

I've created a Desktop Entry in linux, which is set as a default "web browser". That entry gets called every time a request like this is initiated, so I can get the link that the application is calling, but not the PID or some identifying information.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a link with a PID of a process that is calling a "website open" request to operating system"? Do you mean a hyperlink? If so, how would you connect a PID with a hyperlink?

Comment: Yes hyperlink, that is my question, if it is posssible. If you are calling default browser in your OS, for example in word document you click on a link and a default browser opens with that link being loaded. My question is that if there is a piece of information that gets sent to default browser, like PID or name of the application that is requesting that hyperlink open action?